# R: Replacing multiple values across multiple dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

Is it possible to replace values across multiple dataframes in R? I understand that one can replace values in a specified column in one dataframe, as so;

```
df$y[df$y == 200] <- ""
```

However, is it possible to loop this across multiple dataframes? All dataframes contain the same column.

I tried this;

```
list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

for (x in list) {
x$y[x$y == 200] <- ""
}
```

But it doesn't work. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop, you updated `x` as desired, but it is not assigned to the entries in `list`, that's why you didn't see any changes after finishing `for` loop.

---

The following code should work

```
lst <- lapply(lst, \(x) {x$y[x$y == 200] <- ""; x})
```

Note that, please avoid using `list` as a variable name since it refers to the built-in data structure in R. You can use `lst` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To use your code and do these operations inplace you can loop over the list indices

```
lst <- list(mtcars, mtcars*2, mtcars*3)

for (i in seq_along(lst)) {
  lst[[i]]$mpg[lst[[i]]$mpg < 40] <- 0
}
```